# cambiar el estado de true a false sin la necesidad de un botón

Tags: reactjs, react-native

buen dia, como hago para cambiar el estado de true a false sin la necesidad de un botón, tengo un estado "shouldShow" en true donde me muestra el contenido de un View y si le cambio el estado a false no me lo muestra, **pero ahora lo que necesito es que en mi useEffect  tengo una constante y necesito que me permita cambiar el estado de mi shouldShow con solo pasar de true  a false desde ahi sin la necesidad de un botón, lo he intentado pero no he logrado hacerlo.**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, Button, Image, Text } from 'react-native';




const App = () => {
  const [shouldShow, setShouldShow] = useState(true);
  
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    
   misstados = setShouldShow(!shouldShow);
     
   }, 2000);

 return () => setInterval(interval);

 },[]);
  
  
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
     
        {shouldShow ? (
          <Image
            source={{
              uri:
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/old_logo.png',
            }}
            style={{ width: 250, height: 250 }}
          />
        ) : null}
        <Text> 
            Nada
        </Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    margin: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: `misstados =` que es?

Comment: simplemente una  variable para cambiar el estado de  shouldShow, son los intentos que realice y no me funciono.

Comment: si pero donde usas esa variable

Comment: [AQUI](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-feather-4jkgey?file=/src/App.js) use tu código y al cargar la página aparece la imagen y luego desaparece, no sé si es eso lo que quieres.

Comment: o quieres que aparezca y desaparezca constantemente como si fuera una intermitente.

Comment: y para hacer lo contrario ósea pasarlo de false a true como seria .

Comment: Pues lo mismo solo que inicializas el estado en false `const [shouldShow, setShouldShow] = useState(false);` y luego en el **useEffect** le pasas el true `setShouldShow(true);`

Comment: Ahí cambie el código, si entras al link de nuevo veraz los cambios.